# Multiple calls to external static method OR call one internal method, that calls the external static

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods, static

So my question is:

I got a static class with a static method called:

```
static class A() {
     public static MethodA() { }
}
```

and I got another class that will call the MethodA() of the static class multiple times:

```
static class B() {
     public static MethodB1() {
         MethodA()
     }
     public static MethodB2() {
         MethodA()
     }
     public static MethodB3() {
         MethodA()
     }
     public static MethodB4() {
         MethodA()
     }
}
```

Is this the right approach or should I do it like this (call internal function, which is the only reference to the static method):

```
static class C() {
     public static MethodC1() {
         StaticCaller()
     }
     public static MethodC2() {
         StaticCaller()
     }
     public static MethodC3() {
         StaticCaller()
     }
     public static StaticCaller() {
         MethodA()
     }
}
```

I came up that this is a design or philisophy question but is there any technical advantage, like maintainable or scaleable code?

Edit: Or even performance improvements?

Comment: How do those function differ? | If it is only a little, a single function with Delegate Parameters for "beforeStatic" and "afterStatic" functions can do this. | If they do not differ at all, they should not be 4 functions | If they differ a lot - delegates might still work, but the delegate declartions might become so big, a hardcoded function like right now is better.

Comment: In this case, I would prefer the StaticCaller approach. The issue with statics is: What if you need to replace them? Changing the call to `MethodA()` everywhere is both timeconsuming and prone to errors. It really helps if you only have to do this once in `StaticCaller()` | Of course when making something like class A, you should propably have avoided static. My advice is that - except for a few Exceptions - a Instance assigned to a Static Field is better then any static class. At lesat you can have multiple and replace them quickly.

Comment: The exceptions, are stuff like FactoryMethods (have to be static or belong to anothe class), or inmutable stuff like teh Math classes. Collections of constants also count, but I advise using a Enumeration here whenever possible.

Comment: Both class B and class C are faulty! Don't repeat yourself! Both B and C should have just one method that calls this other static method... ;-)

Comment: @WimtenBrink I just made the asumption that example functions with different names have different content besides this call. It just does not mater what else they do for this questions.

Comment: @Christopher, the DRY principle is a well-accepted principle but it is true that you sometimes can't avoid repeating things. But to me it sounds that every method is doing stuff, call static method, then do more stuff. So all methods can be divided into three pieces with a common shared action. That means it is likely possible to merge them into one method that calls other methods for the before and after part. It's a different angle to look at your code.

Comment: @WimtenBrink I am pretty sure what you describe, is what I was pointing out with Delegates. But it really depends just how different the Functions are beyond that call if it is a good idea.

Comment: @Christopher, you won't need delegates. All you need is write one method that has three parts: The preStaticCall, the StaticCall and the PostStaticCall. The pre/post parts could just be switch statements based on an extra parameter. Or delegates. Or something completely different. But to decide what is best, the rest of the code becomes important. But your class would basically have just one method, not four. (And likely some private methods to keep the methods small.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wim ten Brink wrote the answer I would have, so at best I can make additions to what he said:

I loathe working with statics. Replacing the call to one static with the call to another is a pain. For that reason I prefer C. It makes it easy to replace.

But I do actually have two other options that may be worth considering:

**1st**

As I loathe statics, I try to avoid writing them. And all of your classes are still statics, passsing the Problem down. If I need something like this and it has any non-constant field, I would not make it a static. I would instead make it a normal instance-requiring class. And then make a static field that takes a instance of this class. It might not sound like that differnce, but replacing:

```
static staticsProvider SP = new ImplementationA();
```

with

```
static staticsProvider SP = new ImpelentationB();
```

Allows a quick swap. Also if you ever need two or more different instances for different pieces of codes (SP1 and SP2), this is now just one additional static field and instnatiation away. Those are the two big issues of statics taking care off. And you could still use instances in class or function scope too.

Now the WPF way is "If you can not change it, wrap it into something you can change!". So how about option D:

```
//I am not a static
public class D{
    //I am not either
    public void MethodA(){
      //But I do call one for you
      A.MethodA();
    }
}
```

You can then create a static field:

```
static public D SP = new D();
```

If you need more then one static provider? make another field. If you need a different implementation? Extract a Interface (actually a VS IDE Option) or create a abstract baseclass from `D`. change the variables to said baseclasss/Interface. Then make a class D2, wich inherits/implements from what you just created.

Do not want it to change at runtime? const or readonly modifiers. But actually the abiliy to exchange instance at runtime might be a feature.

**2nd**

Rather then trying to cut down on calls for static, how about cutting down on versions of MethodBX and MethodCX?

By using delegates you could hand in the code for the "beforeStatic" and "afterStatic" parts as functions.

This is however only adviseable for really small differences. If you got large differences, writing two large delegates for each call would make it less manageable then just writing the mutliple functions you got now.

**Function call overhead**

There is a cost to calling functions. In effect the CPU has to make a jump. And jumps are still a thing whose cost can be measured. It will propably not mater in the big picture - we are way past the time we pinched CPU cycles. Also, it might be avoided autoamtically:

Native C++ has the [inline](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Statements/Functions#inline) compiler hint.

Afaik .NET does not allow this control. But it does have the JiT and Compiler Optimisations. And those can totally go and inline for your automatically. And for a function like this:

```
public static StaticCaller() {
  MethodA();
}
```

Let me just say that if there are *any* function to be inlined, the ones that look like this *have* to be on the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is considered opinion-based as both methods have their own advantages. Many developers here on SO have their own preference so this is challenging to answer without voiding an opinion.
In class B each call goes directly to method A while in class C the call first has to go through a local method before it can go to method A. This extra step can be considered redundant and thus class B would be preferred.
However, for whatever reason you might have to change the call from method A to method D, from a class you haven't made yet. In that case, you would have to change four methods in class B and just one in class C. Thus class C is easier to maintain and adjust.
Both thus have their pros and cons and class B gives a very minor performance gain. (Literally clock ticks!)
So in general, it really doesn't matter much so my advise is to pick the solution that is best to read for developers. This means adding comments, use proper formatting, use clear method names and try to avoid repeating yourself!
And that latter comment means that both class B and class C are bad practice as each class [is repeating a call to some method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). You should reconsider reshaping those methods into a single method. Which can be tricky as there might be a lot of differences in these methods.

Comment: With the way JiT Optimisations work, it might not even be a performance gain. Such a small function would be ideal ... for that feature where function calls are cut out and replaced by their code, avoiding the call. I can not remember the name right now.

Comment: Inlining. That was the term I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like to rely on JIT optimizations. But a few clock ticks saved on my 3 GHz machine? Meh, don't bother. I have three billion ticks per second so I can waste a few.

Comment: Imagin calling a logging function. Instead of writing everywhere "Console.WriteLine ("string")" just call the appropiate Method Logging(par1 message, par2 host) and this method woll call the "Logger-module" which now calls Console.Writeline("string") once. Besides that, those functions do a lot of different things and can't be composed into one readable. There comes up my question.

Comment: @AbeA. As long as you call the log method once, your code will fall in a pattern precode-log-postcode. This could be made more generic through delegates, conditions or just overriding methods. But to suggest a better optimization, we'd need to see more code. Consider posting the code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a review.